# Open UIPageViewController on specific page, depending on date

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I'm working on a block calendar app starting from the UIPageViewController template provided by Apple. Now I have an array of 365 images, each image used to fill a page. When opening the app, the first page shows - naturally - the first image in the array. Now my desire is that each image corresponds to a certain date (say 12-06-2012), and that when the app is openend on that date, the app opens the page that corresponds with that date. As I'm rather new to Objective-C and UIPageViewController in particular, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: As it stands now, can you flip pages of your application, or is the first image staying there in a "frozen" state, no matter how many pages you turned? If you can flip pages both forward and backward, and next/prior images from your array show up, please edit your question with the content of the following two methods: `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:`.

Comment: There are 366 days in a leap year - 2012 is a leap year :)

Answer (score 0):

`UIPageViewController` does not know the concept of the current page number. As far it is concerned, there is only the view controller it currently displays. You are responsible for providing a correctly configured view controller to the page view controller (and prepare another view controller that is configured for the next or previous page whenever the user turns a page).

Regarding determining the number of a specific day in the current year, have a look at `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`, especially the `ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:` method. Also note that not all users use the "western" Gregorian calendar that most of us are probably taking for granted.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense. So as I understand it, I can keep the array of 365 images, and from there provide the view controller with the image matching today's date (with comparing to NSDate)? Or should I edit the array?